# How to upgrade from Linux Mint 15 to Linux Mint 17?

Tags: linux-mint

How do I upgrade from Linux Mint 15 (Olivia) to Linux Mint 17 (Qiana)? I googled, but the results showed only upgrading 16 to 17. Please help on this.

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at [this collection of upgrade steps](https://gist.github.com/hgomez/7074150):

## 15 to 16:

```
$ sudo sed -i 's/raring/saucy/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
$ sudo sed -i 's/olivia/petra/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

## 16 to 17

```
sudo sed -i 's/saucy/trusty/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
sudo sed -i 's/petra/qiana/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo shutdown -r now
```

### Edit:

For Saucy, the steps are actually (take care of the new, third line):

```
$ sudo sed -i 's/raring/saucy/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
$ sudo sed -i 's/olivia/petra/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
$ sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

Then, 16 to 17:

```
sudo sed -i 's/saucy/trusty/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
sudo sed -i 's/petra/qiana/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
sudo sed -i '/security/ s/old-releases/security/; s/old-releases/archive/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: can i do upgrade directly from 15 to 17?

Comment: I didn't try - and i wouldn't, too. It would be quite risky to do so - but it depends on your needs. It may save time regarding the upgrade process, but it may consume more time repair a broken system using your backups.

Comment: warning,  sound stopped working when i upgraded to 16

Comment: FWIW, I performed this today without a hitch, although I didn't use the sed command as /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list didn't exist. A simple vim /etc/apt/sources.list (*after a backup, of course) was sufficient. 

I think there was one need, during 16-17, to run sudo apt-get install -f but otherwise was seamless.

Comment: My only issue (from 15-16) was with my theme; to resolve this I logged into the terminal and updated the /etc/mdm.conf to use an existing html-theme (Clouds, for example).

Comment: Why is the `apt-get upgrade` necessary at the end? According to http://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade it performs a subset of upgrades performed already by `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Saucy is old enough now that the package server has changed. You need an extra sed command before the `apt-get update` part: `sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list`. Answer should update to reflect this.

Comment: @Dave - thanks a lot for the hint - i've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @tohuwawohu. I just tried it and found that, unfortunately, you have to change the servers BACK to what they were to get trusty packages. Here's a sed command I used to do that for the 16-to-17 piece: `sudo sed -i '/security/ s/old-releases/security/; s/old-releases/archive/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list`.

Comment: OK - got it - done :-)

Comment: Not only did this script fail to update from 15 to 16, it broke a lot of tools in 15 such as Cinnamon. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If there is a need to jump from 15 to 17; why go through the process of upgrade? Backup your files, data, etc. to a USB, download 17 & install it. Will save you all the hassles, risk of repair..

Comment: If Mint is stable enough that upgrading to new versions without breaking things 'just works', what's the point of doing a clean install? Why waste time to backup/restore files, reinstall all the software, and reconfigure/customize the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the procedure directly from 14.04 to 16.04 (Raphaela to Sylvia) and it worked perfectly well (ugh, just had to force cinnamon upgrade) in 1 step.
Less than 15 min, fastest upgrade ever....!!

Comment: The question asked **how** to upgrade from 15 to 17, not whether it is possible to upgrade from 14 to 16.

Comment: To clarify: 14.04 to 16.04 is ubuntu versions Linuxmint is based on. Last Minuxmint 18.3 is based on Ubuntu 16.04. So when I upgrade to "Sylvia", I get Ubuntu 16.04. (at the end I had to re-install cinnamon: apt-get install cinnamon), few minutes more. I dit 18.3 directly, not 17.

Comment: To summarize, I get LM 18. No need to go via 17.